# Neo4j : Does creating nodes with 500 properties slow down the creating process?

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to creating node with 500 ~ 600 columns, as the requirement is show all the properties in a single dataframe/table. The creation of nodes is using bolt driver api from java eclipse.

Also, it would be tedious to select manually so many columns, if there were from different nodes and select from different nodes, in order to show all the properties as tables.

If all the properties were in a single node, I would easily return * properties.

This is how I am trying to create the nodes. The total number nodes to be created is about 20K ~ 40K.

Example:

```
List<String> nodes = {create(s:TEST{a:"", b:"", .... })
    create(s:TEST{a:"", b:"", .... })
    ...
    create(s:TEST{a:"", b:"", .... })
    };
```

This is how, I am creating the does for example:

```
try (Session session = driver.session()) {
    for (String q : nodes) {
        StatementResult st = session.run(q);  
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of iterative approach, one node created at a time, isn't recommended.

You may want to review [Michael Hunger's batching tips](http://jexp.de/blog/2017/03/5-tips-tricks-for-fast-batched-updates-of-graph-structures-with-neo4j-and-cypher/) on better ways to insert your data.

In your case, providing a parameter of a list of property maps allows you to unwind the maps, create the nodes, and add the property values to the nodes directly:

```
UNWIND $propsList as props
CREATE (n:Test)
SET n = props
```

If you run into slowdowns or hangs when inserting, take a look at Michael's advice on using APOC Procedures to batch insert with periodic commits.